# Unable to get actual co-ordinate of moving sprite using registerEntityModifier in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I am moving boat sprite using registerEntityModifier and my boat sprite is firing missile 
I am using boat.getX() and boat.getY() to get co-ordinates but i am not getting actual ones 
that is why my sprite is not appears as it is firing missiles

My Code is given below

public void followPath(Path pPath)
        {

```
            thisObject.registerEntityModifier(new LoopEntityModifier(new PathModifier(50, pPath, null, new IPathModifierListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPathStarted(final PathModifier pPathModifier, final IEntity pEntity) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPathWaypointStarted(final PathModifier pPathModifier, final IEntity pEntity, final int pWaypointIndex) {

                            switch(pWaypointIndex) {


                            case 0:
                                thisObject.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 12,14, true);
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                thisObject.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 12, 14, true);
                                break;
                       /* case 2:
                                thisObject.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 9, 11, true);
                                break;
                        case 3:
                                thisObject.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 3, 5, true);
                                break;*/
                            }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPathWaypointFinished(final PathModifier pPathModifier, final IEntity pEntity, final int pWaypointIndex) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPathFinished(final PathModifier pPathModifier, final IEntity pEntity) {


                    }
            })));
    }
```

Comment: can't get your actual problem.please explain a bit better. When the boat disappears? When you want to get position?

Answer (score 0):

As per my view, you have to create a **Boat** class which extends sprite/animatedsprite as per you need. The **Boat** class, you have to register your path entity modifier.

And for getting actual coordinate of moving boat you have to override onManageUpdate() method. For testing purpose you can log your coordinate and check you get actual one or not.

Comment: thanks I got actual coordinate of boat in onManageUpdate() method. But now  i am unable to call another class method which (shoots missiles from boat) from onManageUpdate() method of boat class

Comment: If you found your answer then please mark as correct so next time we happily help to you.